# Eigenvectors of normal matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a *normal* matrix:
$$
A\in M(n\times n,\mathbb{C})\text{ and }A^* A=AA^*.
$$
Prove that if $v$ is an eigenvector of $A^*A$, then it is an eigenvector of $A$.

Edit: This seems to be a basic fact (stated as obvious in the middle of a proof here: http://www.math.tamu.edu/~dallen/m640_03c/lectures/chapter6.pdf)

I have also seen it referenced in other books discussing normal matrices. I am aware of an ugly proof but was looking to see if the community new of any nice proofs of this basic fact.

Comment: Please add some context or some attempt to solve this.

Comment: I have added some context. I think this is a good question for the site and would prefer if it did not have a negative score.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true. Consider, for example, $A=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$, then $A A^*=A^*A=I$. Each vector is the eigenvector of $I$ but many of them are not eigenvectors of $A$.

Seems like a minor mistake in the text you refer to (proof $(a)\Rightarrow (b)$ is you mean this), they probably wanted to say that there exists a common orthonormal basis of the commuting family of matrices $A, A^*$ and $A A^*$.