# Proving that a normal matrix $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{A'A}$ has same eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Is my proof correct ?.

$\mathbf{A}$ be the normal matrix, and $x$ is the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$, then
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf{Ax} &=\lambda x\\
\mathbf{A'Ax} =& \mathbf{A'}\lambda x = \lambda \mathbf{A'} x\\
& \implies \lambda^2 x
\end{align}
$$
Hence $\mathbf{x}$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda^2$

Comment: Why $A'x = \lambda x$ ?

Comment: @Youem, transpose has the same eigenvalue as the original matrix, right ?.  Now I am doubtful, whether it has got same eigen pair ?

Comment: I doubt also since in this case you are not using the condition of normal matrix

Comment: Eigenvalues yes, but in general the eigenvectors are unrelated. You need to use that $\mathbf A$ is normal somewhere.

Comment: seems like it is a minor error.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1089415/eigenvectors-of-normal-matrix

Answer (score 1):

You only proved one inclusion.

In other words, you proved that if $A$ is normal, then every eigenvector of $A$ is also an eigenvector of $A^{*}\!A$.

However, the reverse inclusion need not hold.

For example, if  $A$ is given by
$$
A=
\pmatrix{
0&1\\
1&0\\
}
$$
then $A$ is real-symmetric, hence also normal.

But $A^{*}\!A=I$, so every nonzero vector is an eigenvector of $A^{*}\!A$, but not every nonzero vector is an eigenvector of $A$.